# Enable network processes after disable in Fedora 26

Tags: linux, networking, fedora-25

I newbie to linux/fedora and i'm doing some network scanning tests (i took a pen-testing course in Udemy ) so for better scanning i killed the following processes, in that specific order:

```
 NetworkManager
 dhclient
 wpa_supplicant
 avahi-daemon
```

I've check with

```
airodump-ng wlp2s0 check //for verifying that the processes are killed
```

and they do  - now i wish to Enable them all back, 
so i run the process name but couldn't get it to work - the only process that i was manage to enable was NetworkManager - all the rest return errors which i guess - suggest i doing it wrong.... perphas the order i did so was wrong...